# Question on a French math text by P. Masani

Tags: complex-analysis, matrices, mathematical-french

I'm trying to translate a paper on matrix-valued functions by P. Masani, published in C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris, 249, 1959, p. 873. (see http://temp-share.com/show/FHKd40yi6 for scanned pdf). My specific question is now as follows:

On the first page, in the first section after the abstract, he writes

"(..) et rang $\Psi$=Cte $\rho$, p.p. où $1\le\rho\le q$, (..)"

where $\Psi$ is a $q\times q$ matrix-valued function on the unit circle.
What does "Cte $\rho$" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Cte" is an abbreviation for "constante", which means, as you can guess, constant.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo do you know if $cte$ is commonly used in other languages rather than romanic ones (I know it's used in Spanish), such as German, English, etc.? Is it a chiefly standard notation for a constant number?

Comment: Unfortunately, my knowledge in non-romanic languages is too limited to answer your question. For example, it would be interesting to know whether _cte_ is used in Russian for example.